# .htaccess Redirect entire directory except pdf files

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect everything in directory2 (`/directory1/directory2/`) except for PDF files to a static URL. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Place this code in `root .htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# it doesn't end with .pdf
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.pdf
# URI starts with /directory1/directory2 then redirect
RewriteRule ^directory1/directory2/(.*)$ /some-where/$1 [L,NC,R]
```